# get some words sorted by occurrence and some words should be ignored from a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, text

hey guys i wanna print some words in an string (sorted according to occurrence) but also i wanna ignore some words like of,the,a,an...etc.

I am using this code:

```
from collections import Counter
cnt = Counter()

for line in text:
  for word in line.split():
    cnt [word] += 1
```

i don't know how to ignore these words. is there any way i could use if statement while printing word
please help me friends. thanks in advance

Comment: So do you have any logic for ignoring that words?

Comment: if you iterate with `for line in text` over a string `text` you will iterate over each character rather then each line.

Comment: i dont know how to ignore words

Comment: @SaketMittal: Please add a sample string and the desired sample output. If you want to do a rather deep text analysis you maybe should choose another approach than doing this manually. Is that a university course related question (since they often want you to do such things)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a set of words you want to ignore and use an if to see if the word is in your ignore set:

```
ignore = {"a","of","the","an"}

from collections import Counter
cnt = Counter(word for line in text.lower()
              for word in line.split() if word not in ignore)
```

You might also want to remove punctuation from your words:

```
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation

cnt = Counter(word for line in text.lower() for word in
              (word.rstrip(punctuation) for word in line.split() 
               if word not in ignore))
```

Comment: Is there any advantage in using a set of ignored words instead of a list?

Answer (score 1):

here you are:

```
from collections import Counter

cnt = Counter()

lst = ["words", "to", "ignore", "is", "a"]
text = "this is a test\n this is a test"

for line in text.split("\n"):
    for word in line:
        if word not in lst:
            cnt[word] += 1
```

produces this output:

```
Counter({'this': 2, 'test': 2})
```

**EDIT:**
As @Padraic Cunningham already stated:
If you care for runtime, you should probably replace `lst = ["words", "to", "ignore", "is", "a"]` with `ign = {"words", "to", "ignore", "is", "a"}`,
because searching in a list has a worst-case runtime of O(n) compared to O(1) for a dictionary (set).